# Angular ngModel different view and value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Does ngModel controller in directive have any option to show something different from ngModel value in view, or i have to write custom html directive for input?
I wrote a comma-separator directive. everything is fine, but ngModel value change from Number to String with `,`.
I mean can i have input with value `1000000` but it shows `1,000,000` in view?

**Update:**
In the input box shows `1,000,000`, but its value be `1000000`.

**Update 2**
I know about `$formatters` and `$parsers`. but the problem is `$formatters` doesn't harm real value, but it works when ngModel changed directly, not by typing in input element, and `$parsers` watch all changes, but change real value too.

Comment: user filters for
example: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Answer (score 1):

use filter to achieve this

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="demoController">

<input type="text" value="{{val | number}}">
</div>
```

**controller:**

var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

```
app.controller('demoController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $location){
     $scope.val = 1000000;
}]);
```

Comment: tnx, your solution doesn't work when input value changed.

Comment: @MeTe-30 : you mean you want some thing like this  <input type="text" value="{{val | number}}" ng-model="val"> ? So that if I enter some value on same textbox, it should change only view but not the model value?

Comment: Exactly! That's what i want!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngModel.$formatters`:

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function (number) {
    return convertToCommaSeparatedString(number);
});
```

In this case model will remain number but input will show formatted string.

[See documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters)

Comment: tnx, you are right, but $formatters works when ngModel change directly, not by typing in input. and $parsers get the changes, but it change the real value too.

Comment: @MeTe-30 Then you shall write parser that will parse formatted value back to desired model.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question...

> "I mean can i have input with value 1000000 but it shows 1,000,000 in view?"

I'm assuming you want a **Number** as the model, but a comma separated **String** in the input as the user types. Based on this assumption, I can answer your question with a **YES**, you can do this; here's how...

Link: [CodePen Working Example](http://codepen.io/SoEzPz/pen/mAgXOW?editors=1010)

> **NOTE**

This example is created in a way that will only allow digits to be entered in to the input. You can change this as you like in each $filter.

Also a word of caution to only use filters that you create that clean the data when it enters the filter. Angular filters are mostly for static values, so they don't work when you want to filter values as they are entered.

i.e. In this case, if we didn't clean the data by removing (/\D/g) all non-digits, we would be splitting, joining, and reversing with commas (and anything else) in the string and the result would crash.

> **HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="inputValueModel" type="text" format-my-view-only />
  Model Value is Number: {{ inputValueModel || "Empty" }}
</div>
```

> **JS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope){});

app.directive("formatMyViewOnly", function($filter){
// You don't have to use $filter, you can do inline work as well as
// functions inside of this directive. I use $filters for code reuse.

  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, input){

      input.$parsers.push(function(value){
        value = $filter("addCommas")(value);
        input.$setViewValue(value); // Set view value.
        input.$render();
        // Then return Number to model.
        return +$filter("onlyNumbers")(value); // Unary Operator converts string to Number. Remove it if you want model to be a string as well.
      });
    } // end link.
  }; // end return.
});


app.filter('onlyNumbers', function(){
  return function(numbers){
    if(invalid(numbers)){ return ""; }
    return numbers.replace(/\D/g, "");
  };

  function invalid(number){
    return !number || notString(number) || noNumbersExists(number);
  }

  function notString(string){
    return typeof string != "string";
  }

  function noNumbersExists(number){
    return number.replace(/\D/g, "").length === 0;
  }
});

app.filter('addCommas', function(){
  return function(stringOfNums){
    if(invalid(stringOfNums)){ return ""; }
    return commaSeparated(stringOfNums.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  };

  function commaSeparated(numbers){
    if(!numbers){return "";}
    return numbers.split("").reverse().join("")
      .match(/.{1,3}/g).reverse().join(",");
  }

  function invalid(number){
    return !number || notString(number) || noNumbersExists(number);
  }

  function notString(string){
    return typeof string != "string";
  }

  function noNumbersExists(number){
    return number.replace(/\D/g, "").length === 0;
  }
});
```