# Angular ng-Model different view and value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Question is similar to this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066118/angular-ngmodel-different-view-and-value)

I want '%' symbol for view only, it should not effect to ngmodel.How can I format this.

I have a text box which will have percentage value, there is a calculation based on that value.So I want to display '%' for view only and ngmodel contrains only value. How can I.

Comment: You can write your own directive, where $viewValue will be changed based on user input & $modelValue will be same as that of what user has `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directive that require ngModel and add a [formatter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters).

```
angular.module('formatter').directive('percentageFormatter', () => {
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) => {
        ngModel.$formatters.push(value => `${value} %`);
      }
   }
});
```

When you require the ngModelController you have to add it to the input element. It is important to give it a name too.

Comment: which error? When requiring an form or an ngModel you have to add it to the html element. <input name="percentage" ng-model="ctr.value" />

Comment: I don't understand write me in the chat if you need help, maybe your environment doesn't understand arrow functions?

Comment: the percentage sign is editable, So it is posible to remove Is there any alternate for this

Comment: Yes, the $formatter takes one or more functions and are executed in the order they whare inserted. Each function takes the value on the view and returns the value formatted. It is possible to add mora than one return statement for each case in the same function

Comment: will it called each time when value changed

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.testNumber = {number:30};
}]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
        //convert data from view format to model format
        return data.replace('%','');
      });

      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
        //convert data from model format to view format
        return data+'%';
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<input my-directive type="text" data-ng-model="testNumber.number" />  <br/>
ng-model value: {{testNumber.number}}
</div>
```

Comment: the percentage sign is editable, So it is posible to remove Is there any alternate for this

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom filter for percentage value

```
angular.module('percentageValueFilter', [])
    .filter( 'titlecase', function() {
   return function(input) {

     if(isNaN(input)
      return input;

     else
      return input + "%";
   }
});
```

use this filter as shown below example in your html

```
{{ yourVale | percentageValueFilter }}
{{ 10 | percentageValueFilter }} // 10%
{{ 'test' | percentageValueFilter }} // test
```